# Question about the preimage using an increasing function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So suppose we have some function $f:X\to Y$ where $f$ is an increasing function, that is, for all $x,y \in X$ we have $x\leq y \rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$. What properties does the preimage of a point have in this context ? Would the preimage of a point $y^*$ still be given as $f^{-1}\!\big(\{y^*\}\big)=\big\{x\in X\;\big|\;f(x)\in\{y^*\}\big\}$, or could we manipulate the definition and use the fact that $f$ is increasing, or does the fact  that $f$ is increasing change anything in this definition ?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The inverse image is what you give. There is no "manipulation".

Comment: I was trying to stay arbitrary but $X,Y= \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preimage of a point, in this context, does have one nice property, namely that if $a,b\in f^{-1}(\{y^*\})$, and $a\leq c \leq b$, then $c\in f^{-1}(\{y^*\})$.

That is, given $X=Y=\mathbb R$, the preimage of a point (or any interval, for that matter) under a non-decreasing map is a (possibly degenerate) interval, though it may be bounded or unbounded, may be closed, open, half-open, or just a singleton (or empty for that matter), and you cannot conclude which of these without more information about the map.

Other than that fact, I'm not sure there is anything special.

##### Remark

If you want to stay in arbitrary totally ordered sets (or even partially ordered sets for that matter), rather than $X=Y=\mathbb R$, then you still have the property mentioned, but you can no longer be sure the inverse image is an interval.  (Here I am defining "interval" as the set of elements between two given elements, possibly including endpoints, or for unbounded intervals, the set of elements greater than or less than a particular element, possibly including that element).

Answer (score 0):

The Term "increasing" shows us a certain behaviour of the function which as you have mentioned as whenever $x≤y→f(x)≤f(y)$, The behaviour does not alter the definitions of pre-image, domain or codomain of a mapping. As Arturo states, There is no "manipulation".